# Symbol for Graph Difference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, notation

Is there any well-defined symbol to denote the difference between the two graphs. The difference between two graphs $G$ and $H$ is defined as the remaining sub-graph $G'$ of $G$ after the subgraph $H$ is removed from $G$ (assuming $H$ is a sub-graph of $G$). For example (the image is taken from [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDifference.html)):

[image]

Note that, $G'$ might not be unique, since $H$ can be positioned anywhere in $G$, Although I can define my own symbol, it would be better to use the symbol that is well defined by the community.

Comment: given that union and complement are well defined, I think the natural suggestion is to use the \setminus for difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations

Comment: @DanielS. \setminus is for set difference right? So we can not use it for a graph $G = (V,E)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use notation $G-H$ or $G\setminus H$, it will often be interpreted as taking the graph $G$ and removing from it *all the vertices of $H$ and any edge incident with a vertex of $H$*. Which is not what you want.

The easiest way to write this would probably be $G-E(H)$, as this makes it clear you are only removing edges, and is unambiguous.

Alternatively, you could just define your own symbol / notation and state what it means up front, this is perfectly acceptable so long as you give a clear definition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Brandon du Preez, we can also define the graph difference between $G$ and $H$, as $G'= (V',E')$, such that:

$V' = V(G)$, and $E' = E(G)-E(H)$

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1439879)

Comment: I have edited the answer. I wanted to point out another way to define the graph difference, based on the previous answer.